# Loading YML files depending on the file name postfix to run against selected profile?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When using environment properties I need to load them from YML file where YML file is loaded if its name postfix matches the profile I am willing to run on.

I've seen this structure in some project but I cannot seem to recreate it in blank testing project:

**application.yml**

**application-dev.yml**

**application-acc.yml**

etc.

The one matching **-P** parameter is loaded when running spring boot app.

When I try to reproduce the behavior on my own new project - only **application.yml** gets loaded. All of the other files are simply ignored...

I don't want dashes to separate profiles inside a single file - I want clear separation by using the structure as I've seen.

**What am I missing, why other profile dependent YML are not loaded?** (I am using latest version so that old bug(1.0.0 Spring Boot) is not applicable to me).

Just in case maven pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <groupId>Application</groupId>
    <artifactId>Base</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.app.config.SpringConfiguration</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "-P" but that's a Maven feature not a Spring one. To set a Spring profile you can use a System property (`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`) or an environment variable (`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`) or the `SpringApplication` APIs.

Comment: I agree, but it still picked up profiles either using P or -D. The problem is that it does not load other YML files, it recognises profiles correctly. Fellow colleague suggested do auto-config something like that, will try after work.

Comment: Maybe your app is not using Spring Boot (despite it being on the classpath)? That's one explanation if you set the active profile and a file with that name is not used.